# Kaminari ignore special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I am using kaminari to generate pagination links throughout all the pages.

However I noticed in some of my links **'&'** was being treated as a special character and being escaped to **'&amp';.**

The returned urls are fine for humans but for bots. These means completely new urls.

Is there a way to tell kaminari to ignore '&' as a special character.

Comment: If the `&` is used as part of the URL apart from parameters it's not standard conform. You should rather escape the URL in all your other code or get rid of it. (good: `someurl.com/page?p1=5&p2=3`, bad: `someurl.com/this&that/page`)